# How to return null instead of undefined when using arr.map(elem => dict[elem]) in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, function, null, undefined

I wrote a simple function to replace values in an array according to a look-up dictionary object:

```js
// typescript
function recode(arr: any[], dict: Record<string, string> ) {
    return arr.map(el => dict[el])
}
```

It works as expected. However, I want the function to return `null` when array values have no match in the look-up dictionary.

So right now if I do:

```js
// array input
const myArr: string[] = ['eggplant', 'tomato', 'carrot', 'cabbage'];

// look-up dictionary
const myDictionary: Record<string, string> = {
    eggplant: 'purple',
    tomato: 'red',
    carrot: 'orange'
};

function recode(arr: any[], dict: Record<string, string> ) {
    return arr.map(el => dict[el])
}

// calling recode()
recode(myArr, myDictionary) 
// returns 
// ["purple", "red", "orange", undefined]
```

But I want the output to be

```js
// ["purple", "red", "orange", null]
```

Is there a simple enough way to achieve this, considering that I'm using *typescript* (not sure it makes a difference)?

[Typescript REPL](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgTwIICcUC4bRQSzAcwG0BdGAXhkIHIBTffABwBsBDMKKgGhiqhDhZ8uPYCzQgO3KqIBGMlvhpViAbgBQa0JFiIAIjmBQc4MQkwAlGqBQATADzY8%20bo4IA%20cjADeagJB1GVnZMKgYAVxRmJU4-PgE%20EJQaGy4-UXEoEJAUNkUqNQBfdTUAMzCwQ2MwGCTQGxoACjEMGDYEEm4bA0yYS2t7V2csKFx3GABKbzUYGZqaKAjq5oA6AQYGmiZyDy7DQk3iccKNWpB6hsRUFG49bqrTcaA)

Comment: Try with `arr.map(el => dict[el] || null)`

Comment: You can always map to your value, or `null` if the value is `null`/`undefined`: `dict[el] ?? null`, but I am curious about the use case for doing this?

Comment: @NickParsons, I'm developing a set of generic utility functions to process data. This specific `recode()` is inspired by an [`R` language function](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/recode.html). I want to reflect the fact that some data is not matched, so `null` seems more appropriate than `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [nullish coalescing operator (`??`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) to resolve `null` in cases of `undefined` (and use a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter to infer the type of values from the `dict` parameter):

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgTwIICcUC4bRQSzAcwG0BdGAXhkIHIBTffABwBsBDMKKgGhiqhDhZ8uPYCzQgO3KqIBGMlvhpViAbgCwAKE2hIsRABEcwKDnBiEmAEo1QKACYAebHnzdnBAHzkYAb00BIOkZWdkwqBgBXFGYlTgC+AT4wlBo7LgDRcSgwkBQ2RSpNAF91LQ0AMwiwY1MwGBTQOxoYBwAVGBoADygaMDsIGGtbR3dXGDYEDw8ACk0YcbRMFJY7cCYELChcAhI4jXm7I2yYVr2ASkxp1sIAaxoEEHKT0gAfGDAIpiYzkl85+fqNCgUTqYhQADoBAxpjQmOQvIdjIRYaQAPyo96fb6lIqabTgaCAiCfWAUBogJrTRCoFDcAxHWrmM4qGAAelZMGmoxgbw+Xx+xHxkBATBo4KYIHw0xSxKYUGZQA)

```ts
const myArr: string[] = ['eggplant', 'tomato', 'carrot', 'cabbage'];

const myDictionary: Record<string, string> = {
    eggplant: 'purple',
    tomato: 'red',
    carrot: 'orange'
};

function recode <T extends Record<string, any>>(
  arr: readonly string[],
  dict: T,
): (T[keyof T] | null)[] {
    return arr.map(el => dict[el] ?? null);
}

const result = recode(myArr, myDictionary); // (string | null)[]
console.log(result);
```

Comment: First of all, thank you very much. This works as expected and very well. Second, would you mind annotating the code just a bit to explain the part of `<T extends Record<string, any>>(arr: readonly string[], dict: T): (T[keyof T] | null)[]`?

Comment: Knowing that `dict` parameter accepts a dictionary of structure `Record<string, string>`, can't we narrow down the `dict` type from `T` to `Record<string, string>`?

Comment: @Emman `T` is already constrained to type `Record<string, any>`. You are welcome to [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) if you want to know more about TypeScript generics and can’t find the answer already.